# Limit object movement to one axis only in Powerpoint

Tags: position, powerpoint, limit, restrict

I'm trying to create a restrict area in which a shape object can move.
Is there a way to limit objects movement to one axis only in PowerPoint? For example, I have created a rectangular shape and placed it where I need it. I want to be able to limit the rectangle positioning so that other users will be able to move it only sideways.
Can this be done in PowerPoint?
I tried to assign a macro with positioning setting but it didn't work.

Thanks a million for your help!

Comment: This can probably be done if you can ensure that you can install an addin on each user's computer. The add-in wouldn't be a beginner project to write. How's your VBA coding skill?